# Is it possible to create a talking homunculus?

Tags: dnd-5e

RAW (MM) state that a homunculus cannot speak. Is there any way to make it capable of speech?

Comment: Are you looking for a RAW way? Because there is always "work it out with DM" way, but if you ask i assume it's not what you want?

Comment: Do you ask how a player can create such a homunculus according to the rules, or is a talking homunculus possible in the world?

Comment: Does sign language count?

Comment: @SeriousBri Can you really "speak" a language totally reliant on sight?

Comment: @Slagmoth Not in my definition but I think it might be the closest we can get in this situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This might work with GM approval and enough casters to keep Polymorph's duration from running out.**

Polymorph it into a beast then cast the Awaken Spell(takes 8 hours) to give it speach. Should work provided your GM allows you to cast Polymorph 8(9 to be safe) times to prevent the Polymorph duration from expiring while casting Awaken. Awaken is instantaneous it may or may not be applied when it reverts (depending on your GM). Or your GM could rule that from then on when you polymorph it into a beast it can speak. Or just flat out doesn't work.  Other than this True Polymorph or Wish would be the only means I can see to give an homonculi speach.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes, it is possible.

The easiest answer is with a Wish spell.

The more realistic method is extremely limited, or extremely complicated depending on how you read it. There is a 2nd level illusion (bard/wizard) spell called *Magic Mouth*. It takes 1 minute to cast, and lasts until it is dispelled.

There are limitations, covered under the spell description.

> You implant a message within an object in range, a message that is uttered when a trigger condition is met. Choose an object that you can see and that isn’t being worn or carried by another creature. Then speak the message, which must be 25 words or less, though it can be delivered over as long as 10 minutes. Finally, determine the circumstance that will trigger the spell to deliver your message.
>
> When that circumstance occurs, a magical mouth appears on the object and recites the message in your voice and at the same volume you spoke. If the object you chose has a mouth or something that looks like a mouth (for example, the mouth of a statue), the magical mouth appears there so that the words appear to come from the object’s mouth. When you cast this spell, you can have the spell end after it delivers its message, or it can remain and repeat its message whenever the trigger occurs.
>
> The triggering circumstance can be as general or as detailed as you like, though it must be based on visual or audible conditions that occur within 30 feet of the object. For example, you could instruct the mouth to speak when any creature moves within 30 feet of the object or when a silver bell rings within 30 feet of it.

So basically, the spell uses your voice, has to be 25 words or less, and the trigger can be as specific or general as you like.

The easy way is to implant a single message that responds to an extremely general trigger. Example: I cast magic mouth, the trigger is that the object exists, and the phrase is, "Destroy all humans," repeating indefinitely at full shouting volume while under the effects of thamauturgy so the voice is incredibly loud.

As for the complicated solution, well, the spell doesn't state that you can't have multiple copies of it on the same object. So you could take a LOT of downtime, and specify a ridiculous number of questions and answers, including one that says, "This homonculus is limited in it's responses, please ask another question," with a trigger of, "Not covered by the other triggers." Even if it wasn't permitted to stack the spell yourself, you could get other casters to do so, resulting in numerous voices, much like Bumblebee from the Transformer movies.

Eventually, you could establish a fairly good basis for question triggers and answers and enable enough for actual speech.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70976/discussion-on-answer-by-lino-frank-ciaralli-is-it-possible-to-create-a-talking-h).

Answer (score 1):

a) There is no specific method for doing so; one would have to research a method.

b) Sign language.

c) Chalkboard.